# Pytrends package in python is not working correctly

Tags: python, data-mining, google, google-data-studio

I would like to download data for the keyword "Investment" for all countries from google trends. I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrends = TrendReq(hl = "en-US", tz = 360)
kwlist = ["Investment"]
pytrends.build_payload(kwlist, timeframe = "today 5-y")
data = pytrends.insterest_over_time()
```

Interestingly, the data I get differs from the actual data in the website. I guess the pytrends do not work correctly anymore. Is there any other easier way to download data than the simple brute force method?